# Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 5000; how to solve this nodejs error?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to run my node server run, but suddenly i have got this error. How can i solve this error? when i command npm run start-dev show me this error. i have change this port, but got same error. Why happend this error? Please help me out, how can i solve this?

here is the error,

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 30000;
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1468:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1533:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1632:5)
    at Function.listen (D:\ecommerce-api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
    at StartDB (D:\ecommerce-api\app.js:34:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ecommerce-api\app.js:42:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1512:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '5000;',
  port: -1
}

Node.js v18.12.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

`my env file`

```
PORT=5000;
MONGO_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecommerce
```

`App js file`

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Database
const connectDB = require("./DB/ConnectDB");
//Paths
const authRoute = require("./Routes/AuthRoute");

//Middleware
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Ecommerce API!");
});

app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRoute);

const StartDB = async () => {
  try {
    connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

StartDB();
```

the package json file below.
`my pacakge json file`

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "start-dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.4",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Something's not right with the `address` and `port` in the debug message

Comment: Remove the semi-colon from your `.env` file. The syntax is just `key=value` and nothing else

Comment: This question can be closed as a **TYPO**

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove `;` in your `.env` file

Answer (score 0):

Can't Access Dotenv PORT

access index.js file port but not access dotenv file port

and I solved this problem

```
netstat -ano | findstr :500
taskkill /F /PID 11076
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error , do not add any spaces in (.env) file , then  you should get the answer

Comment: It was the semi-colon, not any spaces (not that OP has any spaces in their `.env` file)